# Recursion with let and cl-labels or just cl-letf?

Tags: local-functions

I found this code on stackoverflow (from Rainer Joswig):

```
 (defun listFormat ()
   (cl-labels ((place-index (idx l)
        (if (null l)
            nil
            (append (list (first l)) (list idx)
                  (place-index (+ idx 1) (rest l))))))
    (place-index 1 l))))
```

and I changed it by adding a `let` form and `cl-labels`:

```
(defun listFormat ()
   (let ((l '(a b c d)))
   (cl-labels ((place-index (idx l)
                         (if (null l)
                             nil
                           (append (list (first l)) (list idx)
                                   (place-index (+ idx 1) (rest l))))))
     (place-index 1 l))))
```

Is this a good practice? In the code I'm working on I need to establish variables with `let`, then do a recursive function, i.e., I don't want the stuff inside the `let` to be repeated on each recursion. I'm wondering if there is a way to combine this under `cl-letf`. I try this, but it's not liking it:

```
(defun listFormat ()
   (cl-letf ((l '(a b c d))
             (place-index (idx l)
                          (if (null l)
                              nil
                            (append (list (first l)) (list idx)
                                    (place-index (+ idx 1) (rest l))))))
     (place-index 1 l)))
```

complaining of `void function idx`. So, is there a way to combine `let` content that shouldn't be resursed with an inner recursion function?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Recursion as general looping construct is discouraged in Emacs Lisp.  Don't.  This is not Scheme.  Why don't you use one of the following instead?

dash.el:

```
(defun list-format (list)
  (-flatten (--map-indexed (list it (1+ it-index)) list)))
```

cl-lib:

```
(defun list-format (list)
  (cl-mapcan 'list list (number-sequence 1 (length list))))
```

LOOP:

```
(defun list-format (list)
  (cl-loop for item in list
           for i from 1
           append (list item i)))
```

Vanilla:

```
(defun list-format (list)
  (let ((i 1)
        (list list)
        result)
    (while list
      (push (pop list) result)
      (push i result)
      (setq i (1+ i)))
    (nreverse result)))
```

Comment: I noticed that shadowing of the list variable in the last example is not necessary. Do you know why? If one uses setcdr etc. it will mutate the list passed to the function as well but the pop function does not. Maybe I should post it as a question.

Comment: I don't know, but I agree, a new question on this would be useful.

Comment: A lisp without recursion seems a bit tragic.

Comment: It's not it not having recursion, it's about not using recursion to implement something `dolist` or `mapcar` handle just fine.